# jqgrid does not update value from textarea on editrow

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

When I inline edit a row in jqgrid, i put a value from ruleFilter column in jqgrid to a textarea for better editing. When i edit the ruleFilter i can see the $('#ruleFilter').val(); is the new value but, on controller in request the value for newFilter is still the same before the edit.

```
extraparam: {
                ajaxRequest: document.helper.getPageName(),
                screenMode: 'editAssertion',
                listTable: $('#List').val(),
                newFilter: function() {return $('#ruleFilter').val();}
            },
```

Above is extraparam from editrow, i think newFilter is not changing with the edited value from textarea, how can i fix this?

ruleFilter is an Assertion textarea.// i think it is irelevant, but still to mention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try returing the value from textarea back to editing grid